# Change styles based on dark or light mode

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, themes

I want to have a dark and a light theme on my Vue app.
I can create `dark.scss` file and change classes styles and use `!important` property to override styles defined in components.
Or I can use `props` in my components and change className with `v-if` based on the theme.
e.g. set class to `className__light` when theme is light otherwise set to `className__dark`.
which one is better in all situations like performance or time needed to do it?

Comment: I am doing this in my app (Angular, but it should be mainly the same) by changing the class attached to the `body` tag. Then I have two files for each theme 'dark.scss' and 'light.scss' and at the beginning of each file I have `body.lightTheme {...` or `body.darkTheme {...`. I have a select and when I choose a specific theme, I am replacing the current class from the `body` of the page with the new class. I hope this helps you somehow :-)

Comment: @decebal As I said in question this is one of my approach, but I had to set `!important` to my styles in `dark.scss` because my light styles are defined in components and they are scoped so if I don't set `!important`, styles in `dark.scss` not work because scoped styles are preferred.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I set all my rules in the theme files so I can just change the body class and everything gets updated. That was the simplest and clean solution for me. I use Angular Material (something like Vuetify - if you are using it) and I set all the style to be general per theme, because for example I want a submit button to look the same on the entire application. But anyway, this depends mostly on what you want to achieve with your app. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i would not do it with classes. I would create CSS variables with either SCSS or you create CSS variables in `:root`

If you do it with the `:root` method then it should look something like this:

```
:root {
   --background: red;
}
```

Then you can access it in any component like this for example:

```
.class {
   background: var(--background); // the background will appear red
}
```

Now you can change the background color with just 1 CSS variables.

To change the variable with Javascript you just write following:

```
 root.style.setProperty('--background', "green");
```

The problem here is that it isnt supported in IE if you care about browser support.
So you should create an fallback like this:

```
.class {
   background: red; //fallback
   background: var(--background); // the background will appear red
}
```

Comment: so think I have to div with color of `background` defined in `root` and in dark mode colors of them are not same. changing `background` value will affect both of them, What should I do for this scenario?

Comment: what do you mean i dont understand you

Comment: I set variable `background` e.g. to red, I have two `div` with `background-color` of this variable. In dark mode div_1 has `background-color` green and div_2 has blue,so changing variable `background` to green will change `background-color` of both div that is not want I want.

Comment: declare more variables... like `--background-one: red;  --background-two: blue;`

Comment: So you say this approach is better and my first approach to use `dark.scss` file and set `!important` to them?

Comment: no I mean in performance or may my approach makes problem in future?