# Switch all class names

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My team and I are working on a social media application built with React that we'd like to add a dark mode and light mode to. I've demo'd it so that I can write ternary in one class at a time and change state on, and change the css style. I was wondering if there was a better way to implement a dark or light mode or if there is a way to switch all class names at once, i.e. with a switch in the nav bar. I've looked up several tutorials but I haven't found a way to implement it optimally.

Comment: https://preview.pro.ant.design/dashboard/analysis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change styles based on dark or light mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079443/change-styles-based-on-dark-or-light-mode)