# Nuxt js & Vue : The best way to implement a light / Dark mode in a relatively large project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

suppose that in a large project ( on Nuxt JS Framework ) with a number of pages and components, we want to implement the dark / light mode of the website template in an optimal and professional way with toggle a button.
In total, the template is about 8 to 10 colors for each mode, and a few other props, such as shadows and borders, are set to change in each mode. You can change the color of the template quickly and gently by pressing a button.

What do you think is the most optimal, most professional, fastest and easiest way to do this ???

> The project is being developed on **Nuxt Js** framework.
>
> Friends, please explain your suggestion and solution in detail so that it is useful and practical for others :)

Thanks for your comments and answers :)

Comment: are you using vuetify with nuxtjs already?

Comment: @palaѕн  No dear friend, no framework has been used.

Comment: here a solution i wrote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079443/change-styles-based-on-dark-or-light-mode/61079674#61079674

Comment: @Ifaruki  Is it also used for large projects with many variables?

Comment: for 1 color you will need for example:. if you do a dark theme for example then you have a dark color black, a light one grey. then you have a text dark and light. thats 4 variables to create then you need then you will need dark and light color for `<small>` tags for example thats 6 variables, you should first think about how much variables you will need, if you know it then you just change that 6 variables with 1 click

Comment: @Ifaruki  How can this be used in Vue Js components?
For example, suppose we want to change the value of the variables in the root by pressing a button in the header? How should we write this method?

Comment: its pretty simple you create a function and write this here for example ` root.style.setProperty('--background', "green");` make sure you have the variable `--background` in your `:root` and thats all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a try to the nuxt community module: https://github.com/nuxt-community/color-mode-module

Demo web site : https://color-mode.nuxtjs.app/

Answer (score 0):

@Ifaruki How can this be used in Vue JS components? For example, suppose we want to change the value of the variables in the root by pressing a button in the header? How should we write this method? Suppose there are 10 variables in root and we want to change all 10 variables by pressing a button, how should we do that?

Basically, is this the right way to make dark / light, and does it work well? Is this method correct?

> root.style.setProperty('--background', "green");